# Not receiving own XMPP presence stanzas (for other resources) after sending initial presence

Tags: xmpp

After connecting, when I send my initial presence to a server, the server does NOT respond with the presence information of the other resources for my own JID that are currently online (I do receive presence info for users in my roster though). I only receive presence info from my JIDs other resources when another of my resources changes status.

Is this standard behavior? I was under the impression that the server is responsible for sending this information after the initial presence.

I don't know which Jabber server version this running on so I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Is there any way to figure out what other resources are available for my own JID given this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server MUST send you also your own presence and the presence of all your other resources.
see: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-initial

```
an entity is implicitly subscribed to its own presence
```

but I think there could be some extra wording about this in the RFC. Or maybe there is and I didn't see it ;-)

Alex

Comment: Is this the case for the "INITIAL" presence?... for example:

1. I log-in.
2. I send my initial presence.
3. I receive my own presence from any other resources?